# Why is flask rendering the wrong template

Tags: python, flask

`UI = Blueprint('UI', __name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='/static/UI', template_folder='templates')`

`web = Blueprint('web', __name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='/static/web', template_folder='templates')`

My projects uses two different Blueprints which use different templates, the app folder has two subfolders for each blueprint (`UI`,`web`)  and each one has two folders (`static`,`templates`),

```
@UI.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def login():
   
    usr = Admin.query.filter_by(username="admin").first()
    if not usr:
        if request.method == "POST":
            if 'passwrd' in request.form:
                # irrelevant code goes here

        return render_template('create_password.html')


    ## this will be triggered if admin is Found 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['passwrd']:
            ### irrelevant code goes here


    return render_template('Alogin.html')
```

when I try to access `127.0.0.1:5000/dashboard` the templates from the `web` blueprint are rendered

I tried changing the `template_folder` parameter but the wrong template is still being rendered

Comment: it uses first template which match name and you should rather keep them in folders `templates/web/create_password.html`  and `templates/gui/create_password.html` and use `render('web/create_password.html')` or `render('gui/create_password.html')`

Comment: @furas I tried to use `'gui/create_password.html'` , `'gui/templates/create_password.html'` , but i does not help instead it throws an error that it can't find that template

Comment: did you put templates in folders `web/templates/web`, `gui/templates/gui` ? It has to be in subfolders `web`, `gui` in folders `templates`. As I remeber you should see this even it Flask tutorials.

Comment: see Flask tutorial [templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/#templates) in Blueprints. File `index.html` is in `admin/template/admin`, not in `admin/template`, and it is load as `admin/index.html`